# Dynamically creating HTML table and populating with data from localstorage

Tags: javascript, html

So I've managed to store an array of objects in local storage. What I'm trying to accomplish now is retrieving the object attributes from the local storage and inserting them into their own table cells, so that they remain there as long as the data is in local storage (after a refresh or window close).

I wish for the table to generated dynamically with the amount of rows equal to the number of objects in the array (One row 3 cells to display the data).

This is what I've come up with so far; I can see the array of objects and the object's attributes in the local storage, but have had no luck on it still being displayed after a page reload.

```js
var courseArray = [];
window.onload = init;

function addCourse() {
  var course = {
    name: document.getElementById("courseName").value,
    number: document.getElementById("courseNumber").value,
    room: document.getElementById("room").value
  };
  courseArray = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("course")) || [];

  courseArray.push(course);
  localStorage.setItem("course", JSON.stringify(courseArray));
  courseArray = localStorage.getItem("course");
  courseArray = JSON.parse(courseArray);
  
  var row = enrolled.insertRow(1);
  var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
  var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
  var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);

  for (i = 0; i <= courseArray.length; i++) {
    cell1.innerHTML = courseArray[i].name;
    cell2.innerHTML = courseArray[i].number;
    cell3.innerHTML = courseArray[i].room;
  }
}

function clearData() {
  localStorage.clear();
}

function createSchedule(course) {
  var table = getElementById("enrolled");
  var row = document.createElement("tr");
  var cell1 = document.createElement("td");
  var cell2 = document.createElement("td");
  var cell3 = document.createElement("td");
  cell1.innerHTML = course.name;
  cell2.innerHTML = course.number;
  cell3.innerHTML = course.room;
}

function getCourseArray() {
  var courseArray = localStorage.getItem("course");
  return courseArray;
}

function init() {
  var courseArray = getCourseArray();
  for (i = 0; i < courseArray.length; i++) {
    var course = courseArray[i];
    createSchedule(course);
  }
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="StudentStyle.css">
  <title>Student Page</title>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    src = "registerBox.js"
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="all">
    <div class="welcome">
      <h1 class="title" align="center">Student Page</h1>
      <h2 align="center">Class Schedule</h2>
    </div>
    <table id="enrolled" align="center">
      <tr id="titleRow">
        <th>Course</th>
        <th>Course Number</th>
        <th>Room</th>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <div id="registerBox">
      <button onclick="addCourse()">Register</button>
      <button onclick="clearData()">Clear Data</button>
      <input type="text" id="courseName" placeholder=" Course Name">
      <input type="text" id="courseNumber" placeholder="Course Number">
      <input type="text" id="room" placeholder="Room">
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this block of code,

```
var row = enrolled.insertRow(1);
var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);

for (i = 0; i <= courseArray.length; i++) {
  cell1.innerHTML = courseArray[i].name;
  cell2.innerHTML = courseArray[i].number;
  cell3.innerHTML = courseArray[i].room;
}
```

you are creating 1 `row` with 3 `cell` and keep replacing the **same** `cell` data with each loop. To display each `row` of data you have, you have to create **new** `row` and `cells` in the loop, like this

```
for (i = 0; i < courseArray.length; i++) {
  var row = enrolled.insertRow(1);
  var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
  var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
  var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
  cell1.innerHTML = courseArray[i].name;
  cell2.innerHTML = courseArray[i].number;
  cell3.innerHTML = courseArray[i].room;
}
```

And note that the loop condition has been modified.

Answer (score 0):

1) What you get from local storage is a string representation of a JSON struct. You have to parse it to get an array of plain objects. So modify your function getCourseArray() as follow:

```
function getCourseArray() {
  return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("course"));
}
```

2) Your function createSchedule() contain incorrect code:

```
var table = getElementById("enrolled"); // BAD
var table = document.getElementById("enrolled"); // GOOD
```

3) And it is also incomplete. You have to attach created elements to the table, like this:

```
function createSchedule(course) {
  var table = document.getElementById("enrolled");
  var row = document.createElement("tr");
  var cell1 = document.createElement("td");
  var cell2 = document.createElement("td");
  var cell3 = document.createElement("td");
  cell1.innerHTML = course.name;
  cell2.innerHTML = course.number;
  cell3.innerHTML = course.room;
  row.appendChild(cell1);
  row.appendChild(cell2);
  row.appendChild(cell3);
  table.appendChild(row);
}
```